# Return symbolic array elements that meet a condition

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, arbitrary-precision

I have a function to return roots where a quadratic crosses 0:

```
function r=valid_quad_roots(q2,q1,q0)
    r=sort(roots([q2 q1 q0])).'; % first find all roots
    r=r(~imag(r)); % get only real roots

    % remove any roots that are tangents. Only actual crossing points
    slope=2*q2*r+q1;
    r=r(slope~=0);
end
```

`q2`, `q1` and `q0` depend on some parameter, say `theta`, related to the bigger problem I am solving. Across an array of `theta` values from say -pi to pi, I compute corresponding values of `q2`, `q1` and `q0`, and call this function, and it returns a 0, 1 or 2-element array of valid roots. (Just FYI, the bigger picture is that I am integrating some downstream value across `theta`, and this function is called in the middle during that integral.)

This has worked fine with numeric `theta`, e.g.:

```
theta=-1; % theta = -1/0/1 give 2/1/0 valid roots respectively

q2=2*theta;
q1=theta+1;
q0=1;

r=valid_quad_roots(q2,q1,q0)
```

Now I need to extend this function to symbolic `theta` (as part of doing a `vpaintegral` across `theta`). Try this:

```
syms theta

q2=2*theta;
q1=theta+1;
q0=1;

r=valid_quad_roots(q2,q1,q0)
```

Now that `r` is a `sym`, it no longer likes the conditional indexing `r(~imag(r))` or `r(slope~=0)`.

How can I make this function similarly return a `sym` array of only those valid roots that meet my conditions?